# Pygame bullets list. pygame.Sprite.Group. Bullets do not work

Tags: python, pygame

The ship in the project is not firing bullets. the bullet list has a value of pygame.sprite.group but it cannot do anything like adding a bullet or updating. I have made another project very similar (on my page). The other project has pygame.sprite.group inside it and that works. How come this one does not:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
pygame.display.set_caption("this game")


class Background:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/images/cliff.jpg").convert()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


class player_first:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/ezgif.com-crop.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (200, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y

    def draw(self):      #left right
        #screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False), self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


class player_second:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/Giantmechanicalcrab2.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (200, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y

    def draw(self):      #left right
        #screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False), self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))







class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/giphy.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))


    def __init__(self):
        self.xpos = 360
        self.ypos = 360
        self.speed_x = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))
        #self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, False, True), self.rect)

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)



player_one = player_first(0, 0)
player_two = player_first(1280, 0)
cliff = Background(0, 0)
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player_one.speed_y = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player_one.speed_y = 5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player_two.speed_y = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player_two.speed_y = 5







                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    bullet = Bullet

                    bullet.ypos = player_one.ypos
                    bullet.xpos = player_one.xpos

                    bullet.speed_x = 14

                    bullet_list.add(bullet)




            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                # Stop moving when the keys are released.
                if event.key == pygame.K_s and player_one.speed_y > 0:
                    player_one.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w and player_one.speed_y < 0:
                    player_one.speed_y = 0


                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and player_one.speed_y > 0:
                    player_two.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and player_one.speed_y < 0:
                    player_two.speed_y = 0




    player_one.update()
    player_two.update()
    cliff.draw()
    player_one.draw()
    player_two.draw()

    bullet_list.update()

    for bullet in bullet_list:
            bullet.draw()



    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of problems with your code:

- When the space key is pressed, you don't create an instance of `Bullet`, since you forgot to actually call the class (a.k.a. you missed the `()`).
- The `Background` class seems pretty useless. You could use `Sprite` to make use of pygame's built-in features (like using a `Group`) or use a single image as background for a `LayeredUpdates`-group. Other than that, creating a class you only use once just for a single image is overkill.
- Your classes `player_first` and `player_second` are identical. No need to create different classes of objects that are different just in data. Use a single class and pass the filename for the image as parameter.
- You already use `Sprite` for the `Bullet` class. Why don't you use it also for the player class?
- You subclass `Sprite` with your `Bullet`, but a `Sprite` should have an `image` attribute for it to work with a `Group` instance.
- You don't need a `draw` function in a `Sprite`.
- You don't need attributes like `xpos` and `ypos` since you store the position of a `Sprite` in its `rect` attribute (again, to be able to work with `Group` and its subclasses).

Comment: thank you this really useful and I have managed to achieve loads